# Check if some property have values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the following code which is working as expected.
I have two text boxes which change according to a dropdown value(*SelType*).
I added the last two lines of code that when the user run the page for first
time the text box will be disabled.
My question: is there an option  to check if something (any property) in the model is having value then execute this code (last two lines)?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[name="SelType"]').change(function () {

            if ($(this).val() === 'A') {

                $('input[name="Emp.User"]').prop("disabled", true);
                $('input[name="Emp.Password"]').prop("disabled", true);

            }

            else {
                $('input[name="Emp.User"]').prop("disabled", false);
                $('input[name="Emp.Password"]').prop("disabled", false);

            }

        });
//Added code for the init page
        $('input[name="Emp.User"]').prop("disabled", true);
        $('input[name="Emp.Password"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
if(@Model.Condition == true)
{
    $('input[name="Emp.User"]').prop("disabled", true);
    $('input[name="Emp.Password"]').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

In case the script is located in separate file just store the required value in a Hidden Field on a page like that:

```
@{
    bool isConditionPropertyNotNull = Model.Text != null;
}
@Html.Hidden("IsConditionPropertyNotNull", isConditionPropertyNotNull)
```

and then refer to it from the script:

```
if ($('input[name="IsConditionPropertyNotNull"]').val() == "True") {

}
```

Comment: Thanks ,but this script I put in different file so I cannot refer to the model from it... ,I've created new JS file and put the script in it.there is other way to do that?

Comment: Then you need to add a hidden field to a page, assign its value for Model and refer to this field from within script.

Comment: @mr-Im new to java script and asp,can you please provide example?

Comment: Thank you voted up,how should I check if the field have some value?and I do you suggest to do the if of $('input[name="Emp.ConditionProperty"]').val(); if value not equal null...

Comment: Just simply compare result of val() function to null.

Comment: I've tried something like  //if ($('input[name="Config.ProviderId"]').val() === null) { and if I have value in this field it also going trow this code,what am I missing here? thanks!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately you can not have null value in an input. So a better solution is the one provided by me in edited answer. Try this, this definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.User, new {disabled="disabled"})
```

Regarding inside the model I am not sure have seen it. But you read the list of [DataAnnotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)
In your case you can create a custom.

For the password, there is one annotation you can use:

```
 @Html.PasswordFor()
```

Comment: Thanks but how should I do that for password box?

Comment: Use Html.PasswordFor instead of TextBoxFor